# String comparison not complete match

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string, for example:

```
my_string = "Man Utd (Supernova) Esports"
```

And I'm trying to access API data that has this down as `Manchester United (Supernova) Esports`

Now I can just do:

```
If 'Man' in `Manchester United (Supernova) Esports:
   do something()
```

But this is a very simple string with a simple answer. There are a whole host of other string naming convention irregularities. Is there a library that checks how many characters match ? I.e. if 15/31 character match, it's probably the right string. The regex would not be dynamic enough to apply for this sort of thing I think.

I basically want an approximate match, rather than an exact one!

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/difflib.html) should be able to help you with this.

Example:

```
import difflib

print(difflib.get_close_matches("Man Utd (Supernova) Esports", ["Manchester United (Supernova) Esports", "Liverpool"]))
['Manchester United (Supernova) Esports']

print(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, "Man Utd (Supernova) Esports", "Manchester United (Supernova) Esports").ratio())
0.84375
```

Comment: Thanks. Used fuzzywuzzy instead, but this just as good for the task